# Will an ATX PSU fit in MiniITX case?

Tags: power-supply, mini-itx

I want to build a mini-itx computer, but I want to know if I have to buy an special sized (mini-itx) PSU, or if I can go with an standard ATX PSU.

Note: This is the case: [BitFenix Prodigy BFC-PRO-300-OOXKO-RP](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=9SIA25V31E4601)

Comment: check the dimensions of the PSU, then check the accepted dimensions of the case, if the PS is within the dimensions the case it will work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the [official specs](https://www.bitfenix.com/global/en/products/chassis/prodigy#specs) for your indicated case:

> **Power Supply**: PS2 ATX (bottom, multi direction), PSU cage depth 180mm, max PSU depth 160mm

So no, a special power supply is not needed. An ATX power supply is needed, provided it's not longer than 160mm.

The same may not apply to other Mini-ITX cases, so be sure to check it's official specs.

Comment: To go off this answer, keep in mind that some Modular PSU's, although normal ATX in size, cable length, width and braiding may cause the PSU to not fit - Ensure you give yourself some room so you aren't "jamming" the PSU in the case and over-bending cables at their base.